# NLog.config not found in "Temporary ASP.NET Files" directory

Tags: asp.net, nlog

I receive a `System.TypeInitializationException` exception when my ASP.NET web service tries calling a wrapper assembly that uses NLog.

According to the inner exception, the problem is the missing NLog.config as the error message states:

> Could not find file 'C:\Users\###\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\667e44c6\775d7f9f\assembly\dl3\4a628202\6a365e53_dfd9d201\NLog.config'.

When I copy the config file manually to the designated Location, everything works fine. Of course this will fail as soon as the application is rebuilt or redeployed.

Can anybody point out what I'm missing here? The build action for the config file is set to "Content", "Copy if newer" and is copied to the `/bin` directory when building the application.

Comment: If you rebuild your application, is nlog.config in your bin map?

Comment: Yep, it's in the bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a cache issue of IIS express.

This should be fixed by deleting everything under the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder, and then rebuild your application.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. After removing directory "C:\Users\###\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\667e44c6\" and starting the web application again, the directory will be created again and the error thrown again as well.

Comment: Please try also removing your current `obj` en `bin` folders.

Comment: Same result :-(

Answer (score 0):

After removing the wrapper and using NLog directly, it works correctly. The config file is still not copied to the temporary directory but it seems as if when using NLog directly this is not required.